# Speeding up numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy

Using a 2D numpy array, I want to create a new array that expands the original one using a moving window. Let me explain what I mean using an example code:

```py
# Simulate some data
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
t = 20000 # total observations


location = np.random.randint(1, 5, (t,1))
var_id = np.random.randint(1, 8, (t,1))
hour = np.repeat(np.arange(0, (t/5)), 5).reshape(-1,1)
value = np.random.rand(t,1)

df = np.concatenate((location,var_id,hour,value),axis = 1)
```

Having "df" I want to create a new array "results" like below:

```py
# length of moving window
window = 10

hours = df[:,2]

# create an empty array to store the results
results = np.empty((0,4))

for i in range(len(set(hours))-window+1):

    obs_data = df[(hours >= i) & (hours <= i+window)] 
    results = np.concatenate((results, obs_data), axis=0)
```

my problem is that the concatenation is very slow (on my system the operation take 1.4 and 16 seconds without and with the concatenation respectively). I have over a million data points and I want to speedup this code. Does anyone know a better way to create the new array faster (possibly without using the np.concatenate)?

Comment: `np.concatenate` is a linear time operation, making the entire algorithm polynomial time. Use a `list` and concatenate the subarrays, then call `np.concatenate` at the very end. That would be the most obvious way to significantly improve this code.

Comment: But also, doing `obs_data = df[(hours >= i) & (hours <= i+window)]` in a loop is going to be slow. Because again, it scans the whole dataframe each iteration. pandas has some built-in windowing facilities, I  believe, but maybe people with more experience with time series can suggest something better.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Using your code, I get the error `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1` on the line `df = np.concatenate((location,var_id,hour,value),axis = 1)`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Using list helped. I was using pandas but then I thought using numpy could be faster. I am open to any suggestions on how to speed it up even more using polars, pandas or whatever.

Comment: @NickODell just fixed the code. should work now. thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Neither pandas nor numpy data structures can grow efficiently (pandas is essentially built on top of numpy, so it's for the same fundamental reason). This is what lists do best.

Comment: `I want to create a new array that expands the original one using a moving window` Can I ask for a bit more information about why you want to do that? Normally, when using a moving window, you want to apply some kind of average or median to the window, not just copy the data in the window by itself. I assume you're going to apply an average after you expand it, but if you can combine the windowing operating and the averaging operation, your code will be faster than if it creates a really big array and then averages it. So I think to make a good answer we need more info.

Comment: @NickODell I am preparing dataset for a deep learning model. Each window will be a an input matrix. So at the end I will collapse the dataframe using groupby(window).agg(list).Didn't want to complicate things in my question so I decided to go simple here.

Comment: @AminShn Got it - thanks for simplifying. A tip about that is that you can make a numpy array which references a moving window of data within the array, without actually copying that data. This technique also occupies much less memory. It's called a [stride trick](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html). The caveat is that each window must be the same size.

Comment: @AminShn, this `range(len(set(hours))-window+1)` does not make a true window sliding as it does no more than `4000` iterations for `df` size of 20_000 rows. What is the reason of basing on unique hours `set(hours)` but filtering on all `(hours >= i) & (hours <= i+window)` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest We have observations from 5 locations so 4000 from each. Windows are based on unique hours.

Comment: Consider *grouping* the dataframe by hours and *sorting* groups by hours too. This way, the loop can run in quasi linear time (since `window` is a constant and sorting/grouping-by run in `O(n log n)`) instead of a quadratic time. Pandas as the `groupby` function for that.

Comment: @AminShn, "I have over a million data points" - in real your actual `t` can be about `1000_000` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, in my real dataset t is about 1200000.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to iterate, make the `results` array big enough to hold all the values.

```
# create an empty array to store the results
n = len(set(hours))-window+1
results = np.empty((n,4))
for i in range(n):
    obs_data = df[(hours >= i) & (hours <= i+...
    results[i,:] = obs_data
```

Repeated `concatenate` is slow; list append is faster.

It may be possible to get all `obs_data` from `df` with one indexing call, but I won't try to explore that now.

Comment: But obs_data isn't a 1D array, that could fit in `result[i,:]`. It is not just a row of `df`. It is a bunch of rows. And len of `results` is not n.

Answer (score 0):

Not a completely for-free answer neither, but a working one

```py
window = 10
hours = df[:,2]
# create an empty array to store the results
results = np.empty((0,4))
lr=[]
for i in range(len(set(hours))-window+1):
    obs_data = df[(hours >= i) & (hours <= i+window)] 
    lr.append(obs_data)
np.vstack(lr)
```

It is way faster. For the reason already given: calling `concatenate` in a loop is awfully slow. Where as python list can be expanded more efficiently.

I would have preferred something like hpaulj answer. With some array initially created, and then filled. Even if `obs_data` is not a single row (as they seem to assume) but several row, it is not really a problem. Something like

```py
p=0
for i in range(n):
    obs_data = df[(hours >= i) & (hours <= i+...
    results[p:p+len(obs_data),:] = obs_data
    p+=len(obs_data)
```

would do.

But the problem here is to estimate the size of `results`. With your example, with uniformly distributed `hours`, it is quite easy : `(len(set(hours))-window+1)*window*(len(hours)/len(set(hours))`

But I guess in reality, each `obs_data` has a different size.
So, the only way to compute the size of result in advance would be to do a first iteration just to compute the sum of `len(obs_data)`, and then a second to store `obs_data`. So, `vstack`, even if not entierely satisfying, is probably the best option.

Anyway, it is a very visible improvement from your version (on my computer 22 seconds vs less than 1)